# Transforming Array!(Array!T) into a range of ranges

Tags: d

```d
import std.container: Array;
import std.algorithm: map;
import std.range: transposed;
import std.stdio: writeln;
Array!(Array!int) a;
a.insertBack(Array!int(1,2,3));
a.insertBack(Array!int(4,5,6));
writeln(a[].map!((ref a) => a[]).transposed);
```

> Error: template std.range.transposed cannot deduce function from
>   argument types !()(MapResult!(__lambda1, RangeT!(Array!(Array!int))))

I am not quite sure what happens here, isn't this supposed to be a range of ranges? Why can't `D` deduce the type?

How would I transform an `Array!(Array!T)` to a range of ranges?

Answer (score 2):

The template constraint of [`transposed`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#transposed) is this:

```d
if (isForwardRange!RangeOfRanges &&
    isInputRange!(ElementType!RangeOfRanges) &&
    hasAssignableElements!RangeOfRanges)
```

We can use `pragma(msg)` to figure out which of those constraints is failing:

```d
auto m = a[].map!((ref a) => a[]);
pragma(msg, isForwardRange!(typeof(m)));
pragma(msg, isInputRange!(ElementType!(typeof(m))));
pragma(msg, hasAssignableElements!(typeof(m)));
```

For me, it prints:

```d
true
true
false
```

Which means that the range does not have assignable elements.

This is likely because `Array`'s `opSlice` doesn't return an lvalue (in which case the `map` function could also return an lvalue), and there is no way to "unmap" the `a[]` slice into the array to support assignment to `a` through the `Map`.

As a workaround, you can use an `Array` of slices:

```d
Array!(int[]) a;

a.insertBack([1,2,3]);
a.insertBack([4,5,6]);
writeln(a[].transposed);
```

Comment: `hasAssignableElements!(typeof(s[]))` yields `true`. So, isn't it `map`'s "fault"?